# PowerShell Get-Winevent by Keywords and Provider Name issues

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and have been learning quite a bit. But still more to go. So my code isn't the tightest.

I've created an Event-log search tool. It allows me to search via ID, error level, key word, etc.  For the most part, it works, with the exception of the keywords and provider name.

Currently, when trying to search the logs for a keyword or set of keywords, the script prompts the error message:

> Get-WinEvent : The specified image file did not contain a resource section
>       At C:\Users\Rob\Google Drive\Powershell\Get-logs.ps1:65 char:9
>       +         Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname=$Log} -ComputerName $Computer |  ...
>       +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], EventLogException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The specified image file did not contain a resource section,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

Problem is, I am not understanding the ps1.65 char:9 bit. The script then continues on and get's me old irrelevant data from the logs.

Here is the code for the two area's i'm having issue. Full code at the end.

Keyword Search:

```
elseif ($Kwrd -gt "a"){
    foreach ($Kwrd in $Kwrd)
    {
        Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname=$Log} -ComputerName $Computer | where-object  { $_.Message -like "*$Kwrd*" }  | Sort-Object TimeGenerated -Descending | Select-Object -First $Maxnum | Format-List  
        }
    }
```

Provider Name Search:

```
elseif ($Prov.Length -gt 1){
        Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname=$Log} -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object {($_.ProviderName -like "*$Prov*")}  | Sort-Object TimeGenerated -Descending|Select-Object -First $Maxnum | Format-List  
        }
```

So for example, if i wanted to search the application log for the provider name System Restore, (Which I have a few in there from the Revo application i ran recently) this is what the script does.

```
Enter Computer or EXIT to quit: office
Enter log set to retrieve: application
Enter Instance ID or leave blank: 
Enter number of logs to retrieve: 10
Enter error level or leave blank: 
Search logs by keyword or leave blank: 
Search by Provider or leave blank: System Restore
Get-WinEvent : The specified image file did not contain a resource section
At C:\Users\Rob\Google Drive\Powershell\Get-logs.ps1:65 char:9
+         Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname=$Log} -ComputerName $Computer |  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], EventLogException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The specified image file did not contain a resource section,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand


PS C:\Users\Rob>
```

It's the same issue for the keyword search,. Same error message. Only difference is the line number changes from 65 to 61, since the code is on line 61.

It's not perfect, but i'm learning as I go. Here's the full script. Any idea's how I can get the information from the logs without the error?

```
Clear-Host

while (1 -ne 2){

$Computer = $Null
$IDNum = $Null
$Lvl = $Null
$Kwrd = $Null
$Prov = $Null


Write-Host ''
$Computer = Read-Host "Enter Computer or EXIT to quit"
if ($Computer -eq "EXIT") {exit;}

$Log = Read-Host "Enter log set to retrieve"
$IDNum = Read-Host "Enter Instance ID or leave blank"
$IDNum = $IDNum.Split(',')
$MaxNum = $MaxNum = Read-Host "Enter number of logs to retrieve"
$Lvl = Read-Host "Enter error level or leave blank"
$Lvl = $Lvl.Split(',')
$Kwrd = Read-Host "Search logs by keyword or leave blank"
$Kwrd = $Kwrd.Split(',')
$Prov = Read-Host "Search by Provider or leave blank"




if ($IDNum.Length -gt 1){

    foreach ($IDNum in $IDNum)
    {
        Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName=$Log; ID=$IDNum} -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object { ($_.ID -eq "*$IDNum*")} |Sort-Object TimeGenerated -Descending | Select-Object -First $Maxnum| Format-List 
        }
    }

elseif ($Lvl -gt 1 ){
    foreach ($Lvl in $Lvl)
    {
        Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName=$Log;Level=$lvl} -ComputerName $Computer -MaxEvents $MaxNum |Select-Object -First $MaxNum | Sort-Object TimeGenerated -Descending  | Format-List 
        }
    }

elseif ($Kwrd -gt "a"){
    foreach ($Kwrd in $Kwrd)
    {
        Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname=$Log} -ComputerName $Computer | where-object  { $_.Message -like "*$Kwrd*" }  | Sort-Object TimeGenerated -Descending | Select-Object -First $Maxnum | Format-List  
        }
    }
elseif ($Prov.Length -gt 1){
        Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname=$Log} -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object {($_.ProviderName -like "*$Prov*")}  | Sort-Object TimeGenerated -Descending|Select-Object -First $Maxnum | Format-List  
        }

else {
         Get-WinEvent -LogName $Log -ComputerName $Computer  | Sort-Object TimeGenerated -Descending| Select-Object -First $MaxNum | Format-List 
     }



} else{

Clear-Host
$log = $IDNum = $MaxNum = $Lvl = $Kwrd = $Prov = $Null
continue
Write-Host ''
Write-Host ''
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please read what a [mcve] and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50539584/edit) your question accoordingly. [SO] isn't a debuggung service. Also your script can't be complete line 65 contains a `write-host` which isn't the error reported.

Comment: Also reread `Get-Help about_foreach` it states ` foreach ($<item> in $<collection>){<statement list>}` item and collection can't be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I'm Running ISE as admin.

Couple of comments

1) I can't recreate the error (your script ran fine on my machine) but it's behaving as though its trying to open/read an image file (very odd).

2) I tried running `get-winevent` with no parameters and I got many `get-winevent : The data is invalid` errors. When I researched this error, I learned that`get-winevent` seems to be a buggy/problematic/fussy `cmdlet`. So, I suggest you try `get-eventlog` instead

3)  You're invoking `Get-WinEvent` inside a loop which makes the program take much longer to run then necessary. I suggest you execute `Get-EventLog` (see comment  #2 above) one time and pipe the output to `out-gridview`. For example:

`Get-EventLog -LogName application | out-gridview -Title "App log events"`

Then, use the `out-gridview` filters to display only the output  you want to see.

Example output for the command above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. still trying to combine some functions, but it's working.